# Stomping WP_Query in author archive to facilitate pagination with custom queries

Tags: wp-query, pagination, author, offsets, loop

I am using `get_posts` and `get_comments` to build several loops on the page, at which I am having some issues in pagination.

I have the global posts per page option **(Settings > Reading)** set to **10**, and this seems to vary the problem. As of now, I can easily get to **Page 2** - http://dev.ashfame.com/author/ashfame/page/2/, but **Page 3** returns a **404**.

If I lower the global value, I get to have more paginated pages but not all (lesser number than how many there should be).

**Update:** I just tried setting my custom setting as 2 (and the global one too), and WordPress should paginate until **page 4** (I have **7** items to show) but now it does but also **page 5 & 6. 7** gives **404**. Why? How do I troubleshoot this thing now?

**Progress:** @t31os helped me figure out that its the WP default query on the page which is setting up the pagination for that page. Now I can think of one way to kill the default WP query on that page (but how?) and then how would I further paginate the **author.php** page? Or is there any other way of doing it?

**Current code:**

```
<?php

            $author_details = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

            // Posts Per Page option
            // $ppp = get_option('posts_per_page');
            $ppp = 1; //custom setting, if you want to obey the global setting here, comment this line and uncomment the above line

            if (!is_paged()) {
                $custom_offset = 0;
            } else {
                $custom_offset = $ppp*($paged-1);
            }

            echo '<h1>Author ID : '.$author_details->ID.', Page : '.$paged.', Custom Offset : '.$custom_offset.'</h1>';

            ?>

            <h2>Articles</h2>

            <?php
            $args = array(
            'numberposts' => $ppp,
            'offset' => $custom_offset,
            'category' => 7,
            'author' => $author_details->ID
            );

            $posts_data = get_posts( $args );

            // print_r($posts_data);

            if ( count( $posts_data ) > 0 ) {               
                echo '<ul>';                
                foreach ( $posts_data as $post ) {                      
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
                }               
                echo '</ul>';
            } else {
                echo '<p>No articles by this user</p>';
            }           
            ?>

            <h2>Journals</h2>

            <?php
            $args = array(
            'numberposts' => $ppp,
            'offset' => $custom_offset,
            'category' => 6,
            'author' => $author_details->ID
            );
            $posts_data = get_posts( $args );

            // print_r($posts_data);

            if ( count( $posts_data ) > 0 ) {               
                echo '<ul>';                
                foreach ( $posts_data as $post ) {                      
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
                }               
                echo '</ul>';
            } else {
                echo '<p>No journals by this user</p>';
            }
            ?>

            <h2>Questions</h2>

            <?php
            $args = array(
            'numberposts' => $ppp,
            'offset' => $custom_offset,
            'category' => 3, // parent category ID is enough
            'author' => $author_details->ID
            );
            $posts_data = get_posts( $args );

            // print_r($posts_data);

            if ( count( $posts_data ) > 0 ) {               
                echo '<ul>';                
                foreach ( $posts_data as $post ) {                      
                    $category_array = get_the_category( $post->ID );
                    $category_name = $category_array[0]->name;
                    $category_permalink = get_category_link( $category_array[0]->term_id );
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a>
                    <br />In: <a href="'.$category_permalink.'">'.$category_name.'</a><br />'.get_comments_number( $post->ID ).' Answers</li>';
                }               
                echo '</ul>';
            } else {
                echo '<p>No questions by this user</p>';
            }
            ?>

            <h2>Answers</h2>

            <?php
            $args = array(
            'user_id' => $author_details->ID,
            'number' => $ppp,
            'offset' => $custom_offset,
            'status' => 'approve'
            );
            $answers_list = get_comments( $args );

            // print_r($answers_list);

            if ( count( $answers_list ) > 0 ) {
                $date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach ( $answers_list as $answer ) {
                    echo '<li>Answer: '.substr( $answer->comment_content, 0, 20 ).'..<br />'.date( $date_format, strtotime( $answer->comment_date ) ).'<br />Question: <a href="'.get_permalink( $answer->comment_post_ID ).'">'.get_the_title( $answer->comment_post_ID ).'</a></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            } else {
                echo '<p>No answers by this user</p>';
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: where is the code that prints out the pagination?, also what are you tring to paginate articles? jurnals? questions? answer? all of them? and as far as i can see is that you should use `wp_reset_postdata();` after each foreach loop.

Comment: @Bainternet I am not printing out pagination links as of now, just modifying the address bar directly. Is there an easy way? Also, I am not using `setup_postdata()`, I am directly iterating on the result of `get_posts()`. Yes, I am paginating all of them. Please take a look at a single section of the code, others are similar.

Comment: Set `posts_per_page` to your desired value, keep doing what you're doing with the offset, but explicitly set `paged` to `1`.. and see if things then behave correctly..

Comment: @t31os where should I set `paged` exactly?

Comment: Inside your `$args` array along with the other values. :)

Comment: @t31os No effect and I wasn't even sure of what effect it will bring. More ideas please!

Comment: Fresh head this morning, the issue is that your author page has a **main query** that still runs in the background, ie. a regular loop, the paging that works is in connection with that query, eg. when the main query(unused in your code) has results for the given page you see data, else you're lobbed to a 404.. In short, the query that happens in the background is determining whether the current page is a 404.

Comment: @t31os Hmm that makes sense, so how do I negate its effect or kill it altogether?

Comment: That's a good question but not one i have an answer for unfortunately(unsetting the paged value in the main query may help), but that might make a better description and heading for your question, so other users know the problem you're trying to solve better..

Comment: @t31os Thanks for helping so far! I have edited the question, please take a look. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an ajax solution if you're interested(i needed the practice doing it anyway).. :)

Comment: @t31os Awesome! I am yet to study how to do Ajax within WordPress. So it will take me some time to check it out and then I will study the code and provide some feedback. Thanks a ton! :D

Comment: Updated the code again, will paginate comments and posts using Ajax now... :) And also fixed the coding errors in the first sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>**t31os says:**</sub> <sub>[See edit history for previous code and comments]</sub>

### Using Ajax to paginate your queries

I've put together some code that will fetch your posts and comments via ajax using simple prev/next navigation via ajax.

**1)** Replace all the code you posted in your **author.php** with the following..

```
<?php $cat_settings = array( 'Articles' => 7, 'Journals' => 6, 'Questions' => 3 ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'author_ajax_catposts', $cat_settings ); ?>
```

**2)** Create a Javascript file in your theme's directory called `authorposts.js` and place the following code into that file.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    
    if( 'undefined' == typeof( aacVars ) )
        return;
    
    $('.aacnav').click(function() {
        
        var r = $( $(this).attr('href') );
        var a = $( $(this).attr('href') + '-ap' );
        var c = this.className.split(' ');
        
        if( 
            'undefined' == typeof( c ) || 
            'undefined' == typeof( r ) || 
            'undefined' == typeof( a ) 
        )
            return false;
        
        var d = { 
            action:      aacVars.posts_action, 
            _ajax_nonce: aacVars.nonce,
            author:      aacVars.author,
            category:    $(this).attr('href')
        };
        
        p = parseInt( a.text() );
        c = c.pop();
        
        switch( c ) {
            case 'aacnext':
                if( r.children('p.nomore').length )
                    return false;
                d.page = p + 1;
            break;
            case 'aacprev':
                if( p < 2 )
                    return false;
                d.page = p - 1;
            break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        
        $.post( aacVars.ajaxpth, d, function( res ) {
            if( '-1' == res ) {
                alert( 'auth failed' );
                return false;
            }
            $( r ).html( res );
            $( a ).text( d.page );
        });
        
        return false;
    });
    
    $('.aacnavc').click(function() {
        
        var r = $( '#aac-comments' );
        var n = $( '#aac-comments-ap' );
        var l = $(this).attr('href');
        
        if( 
            'undefined' == typeof( n ) || 
            'undefined' == typeof( r ) 
        )
            return false;
        
        var d = { 
            action:      aacVars.comments_action, 
            _ajax_nonce: aacVars.nonce,
            author:      aacVars.author
        };
        
        p = parseInt( n.text() );
        
        switch( l ) {
            case '#next':
                if( r.children('p.nomore').length )
                    return false;
                d.page = p + 1;
            break;
            case '#prev':
                if( p < 2 )
                    return false;
                d.page = p - 1;
            break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        
        $.post( aacVars.ajaxpth, d, function( res ) {
            if( '-1' == res ) {
                alert( 'auth failed' );
                return false;
            }
            r.html( res );
            $( n ).text( d.page );
        });
        
    });
    
});
```

**3)** Copy the following code into your theme's **functions.php** file.

```
class Author_Ajax_Cats {
    
    private $posts_per_page    = 3;
    private $comments_per_page = 1;
    private $posts_action      = 'aac-posts';
    private $comments_action   = 'aac-comments';
    private $js                = array();
    
    public function __construct() {
        
        add_action( 'parse_request',                            array( $this, 'aac_parse_request' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $this->posts_action,    array( $this, 'aac_ajax_posts' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_' .        $this->posts_action,    array( $this, 'aac_ajax_posts' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $this->comments_action, array( $this, 'aac_ajax_comments' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_' .        $this->comments_action, array( $this, 'aac_ajax_comments' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',                       array( $this, 'aac_enqueue_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'author_ajax_catposts',                     array( $this, 'aac_print_posts' ) );
    }
    public function aac_parse_request( $wp ) {
        
        if( !isset( $wp->query_vars['author_name'] ) || is_admin() )
            return;
        
        $wp->query_vars['paged'] = 1;
        
    }
    private function setup_js_vars() {
        
        global $wp_query;
        
        $this->js['author']          = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
        $this->js['posts_action']    = $this->posts_action;
        $this->js['comments_action'] = $this->comments_action;
        $this->js['nonce']           = wp_create_nonce( 'noncekey' );
        $this->js['ajaxpth']         = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );
    }
    public function aac_enqueue_scripts() {
        
        if( !is_author() )
            return;
        
        $this->setup_js_vars();
        
        wp_register_script( 'author-ajax', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/authorposts.js', array( 'jquery' ), time(), true );
        wp_localize_script( 'author-ajax', 'aacVars', $this->js );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'author-ajax' );
    }
    public function aac_ajax_comments() {
        
        if( !isset( $_POST['page'] ) || !isset( $_POST['author'] ) )
            die;
        
        check_ajax_referer( 'noncekey' );
        
        $authID = absint( $_POST['author'] );
        $paged  = absint( $_POST['page'] );
        
        $args = array(
            'user_id' => $authID,
            'number'  => $this->comments_per_page,
            'offset'  => ( ( $paged - 1 ) * $this->comments_per_page ),
            'status'  => 'approve',
            'type'    => 'comment'
        );

        $answers_list = get_comments( $args );
        if( empty( $answers_list ) ) {
            printf( '<p class="nomore">%s</p>', __( 'No more answers by this user.' ) );
            die;
        }
        $_comment_walk = new Walker_Comment;
        
        echo '<ul>';
        $_comment_walk->paged_walk( $answers_list, 0, 1, $this->comments_per_page, array( 
            'style' => 'ul', 
            'avatar_size' => 15, 
            'max_depth' => 1, 
            'callback' => array( $this, 'author_comment_walker' ) 
        ) );
        echo '</ul>';
        
        die;
    }
    public function aac_ajax_posts() {
        
        if( !isset( $_POST['page'] ) || !isset( $_POST['category'] ) || !isset( $_POST['author'] ) )
            die;
        
        check_ajax_referer( 'noncekey' );
        
        $catID  = absint( str_replace( '#aac-', '', $_POST['category'] ) );
        $authID = absint( $_POST['author'] );
        $paged  = absint( $_POST['page'] );
        
        $args = array(
            'paged'       => $paged,
            'numberposts' => $this->posts_per_page,
            'author'      => $authID,
            'cat'         => $catID
        );
        $posts = get_posts( $args );

        if( empty( $posts ) )
            die( sprintf( '<p class="nomore">%s</p>', __( 'No more posts.' ) ) );
        
        $this->do_posts( $posts );
        
        die;
    }
    public function aac_print_posts( $cats = array() ) {
        
        //get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'category', '<ul><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' )
        
        foreach( $cats as $heading => $id ) {
            $args = array( 
                'cat'         => $id,
                'paged'       => 1, // Always the first page on load
                'numberposts' => $this->posts_per_page, 
                'author'      => $this->js['author']
            );
            $posts = get_posts( $args );
            
            printf( '<h2>%s</h2>', $heading );
            
            if( empty( $posts ) ) {
                printf( '<div><p class="nomore">%s</p></div>', __( 'No posts.' ) );
                continue;
            }
            
            printf( '<div id="aac-%d" class="aac-result">', $id );
            
            $this->do_posts( $posts );
            
            printf( '</div><div>' );
            printf( '<p class="alignright">Page: <span id="aac-%1$d-ap">1</span></p><p class="alignleft"><a class="aacnav aacprev" href="#aac-%1$d">%2$s</a> <a class="aacnav aacnext" href="#aac-%1$d">%3$s</a></p>', $id, __('Previous'), __('Next') );
            printf( '<br class="clear" /></div>' );
        }
        ?>

        <h2>Answers</h2>

        <?php
        $args = array(
            'user_id' => $this->js['author'],
            'number'  => $this->comments_per_page,
            'status'  => 'approve',
            'type'    => 'comment'
        );
        $answers_list = get_comments( $args );
        if( empty( $answers_list ) ){
            printf( '<p>%s</p>', __( 'No answers by this user' ) );
            return;
        }
        $_comment_walk = new Walker_Comment;
        
        printf( '<div id="aac-comments"><ul>' );

        $_comment_walk->paged_walk( $answers_list, 0, 1, $this->comments_per_page, array( 
            'style' => 'ul', 
            'avatar_size' => 15, 
            'max_depth' => 1, 
            'callback' => array( $this, 'author_comment_walker' ) 
        ) );
            
        printf( '</ul></div><div><p class="alignright">Page: <span id="aac-comments-ap">1</span></p><p class="alignleft"><a class="aacnavc" href="#prev">%s</a> <a class="aacnavc" href="#next">%s</a></p><br class="clear" /></div>', __('Prev'), __('Next') );
    }
    private function do_posts( $posts, $term_id = 0 ) {
    
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $posts as $post )
            printf( '<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', get_permalink( $post->ID ), get_the_title( $post->ID ) );
        echo '</ul>';
        
    }
    public function author_comment_walker( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
        
        $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; 
        ?>
        
        <li>
            <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
                <div>
                    <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'], $default = '<path_to_url>' ); ?> <?php echo get_comment_author_link(); ?> answered 
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ); ?></a> on <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>"><?php printf( __( '%1$s at %2$s' ), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time() ); ?></a>
                    <?php //edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)' ),'  ','' ); ?>
                </div>
                <?php // comment_text() ?>
                <p><?php comment_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
$aac = new Author_Ajax_Cats;
```

**4)** Fire up an author page and see how the results look and to check my code works for you.

#### How it looks locally with test data.

*Click to view larger version, scaled down for the answer*

[image]

#### Live demo of the code in action:** (test site)

http://t31os.onatha.com/author/t31os/

**5)** Provide some feedback.. :)

I hope that helps...

Comment: Till the point we are not killing any kitten by hacking any core file, it works for me ;)

This works great, the way I want. Any chance can I set empty pages to 404, just need to know the place (GLOBALS only perhaps?), if possible. I can access any page right now :)

Comment: ok never mind that, I checked some code & its going to be some more complicated with additional queries. But do you have any suggestions for how I generate paginated links? I mean with the current code, I can't know if there is anything left further so that I should create a link to the next page or not. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you considered just using Ajax to fetch the posts and using prev / next links for each ajaxified set of posts? The ajax response could return a "No more posts" message quite easily.. (and would avoid the need for lookup queries to count the posts an author has in a particular category).